# how to update wixproj file after wix toolset update

Tags: wix

what is the way to update ones wixproj file after a wix toolset update?

I updated from v3.8 to v3.9 today but when I look into the wixproj file I still see the old paths etc. pointing to v3.8.

Do I just manually change them?

Answer (score 0):

If you put the following at the top of the project file,

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <WixTargetsPath Condition=" '$(WixTargetsPath)' == '' AND '$(MSBuildExtensionsPath32)' != '' ">$(MSBuildExtensionsPath32)\Microsoft\WiX\v3.x\Wix.targets</WixTargetsPath>
    <WixTargetsPath Condition=" '$(WixTargetsPath)' == '' ">$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\Microsoft\WiX\v3.x\Wix.targets</WixTargetsPath>
</PropertyGroup>
```

use the `WixExtDir` for paths to extensions,

```
<HintPath>$(WixExtDir)\WixFirewallExtension.dll</HintPath>
```

and this at the bottom

```
<Import Project="$(WixTargetsPath)" />
```

You would never have to update the project file when updating WiX 3.x

Comment: Very odd, I've just opened a project with all this set correctly and it still claims it's incompatible.